# How to remove "tradeexchange.com" link opening everytime in Chrome[ubuntu 15.10]

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, malware

I am on Ubunbtu 15.10. In either Firefox or Chrome, everytime i click a link, a rouge link called "tradeexchange.com" opens. I tried everything - but i am unable to remove this. I cleared all the cache, cookies etc but no change.I saw similar articles on how to remove it but no success after trying them.
Any hint how to remove this irritiating tradeexchange.com hyperlink malware from Chrome?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to your Addons <kbd>Ctlr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Click on the `Extensions` tab on the left.
3. Look for the `AdBlock Super` Addon and remove it then restart Firefox.

Source: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/6UpyKspMv7o/0qjzITOcP0kJ